# Как удалить или очистить master в gitbucket?

Tags: git

Как удалить или очистить master в gitbucket?

Comment: Зависит от того, что вы под этим понимаете. Вы хотите удалить файлы, но оставить историю, или удалить вообще всё?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, вообще все

Comment: В таком случае нужно сделать reset master'а на первый коммит в истории, а затем push --force. ВНИМАНИЕ! эта операция необратима! Но проще создать новый чистый репозиторий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd /path/to/project/
git checkout master 
git rm . -rf --cached
git commit -m "master clear"
git push
```